# jquery grid not filled with JSon data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui

Hi I am not able to get the data from JSON loaded on to grid,

HEre is my code for the grid wich displays the stock prices for the stock for a user  :

```
      $(document).ready(function () { 
        //  $("#jQGrid").html("<table id=\"list\"></table><div id=\"page\"></div>");
            jQuery("#jqTable").jqGrid({
                url:jqDataUrl,
                datatype: "json",
                mtype: "POST", 
                height: 250,
             // Specify the column names
                colNames: ["SYMBOL", "LAST", "CHANGE", "%CHANGE","HIGH/LOW"],

                // Configure the columns
                colModel: [
                { name: "SYMBOL", index: "SYMBOL", width: 200, align: "left" },
                { name: "LAST", index: "LAST", width: 200, align: "left" },
                { name: "CHANGE", index: "CHANGE", width: 200, align: "left" },
                { name: "%CHANGE", index: "%CHANGE", width: 200, align: "left"},
                { name: "HIGH/LOW", index: "HIGH/LOW", width: 200, align: "left"}
                ],
                jsonReader : {
                    root: "rows",
                    page: "page",
                    total: "total",
                    records: "records",
                    cell: "cell", 
                    id: "id",
                },
                multiselect: false,
               // paging: true,
              //  rowNum:10,
              //  rowList:[10,20,30],
                pager: $("#jqTablePager"),
                loadonce:true,
                caption: "WatchList"
            }).navGrid('#jqTablePager',{edit:false,add:true,del:true});
        }
```

});

But when i try and run the code i am not able to get the contents on to the table (but the grid loads with no content)

And My json is of the form :

```
{
total: "1",
 page: "1",
 records: "2",
rows : 
[
{id:"1", cell:["cell11", "cell12", "cell13","cell13","cell13"]},
{id:"2", cell:["cell21", "cell22", "cell23","cell13","cell13"]}
]
}
```

Please help me solve the problem

Comment: The names in colModel are used as HTML element IDs, so they should follow the rules for these. `%` and `/` are not supposed to be used in element IDs. I don't know if this will solve the problem, though.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**:

I discovered that if you do not put `repeatitems:true` option into json reader, jqGrid assumes that you are using json dot notation. When you put it into jsonReader, your data is properly loaded. Here is working example: http://jsfiddle.net/a5e5F/3/

---

*Old version*:

I played a lot with your jqgrid code, and it seems that there is a bug in this version of jqGrid, which causes your jsonReader not to work. It reads data directly, ignoring root element and assuming that your data is array of json objects in format

```
{propertyName1:'PropertyValue1', propertyName2:'PropertyValue2', ...}
```

You can see what I mean on http://jsfiddle.net/a5e5F/2/

If you replace `data:rows` with `data:data` (your format of data), it does not load data. Maybe you should try to change your json data to use real json format (with properties named as columns)?

I have been trying a ton of stuff, changing column names to check for issue in @Barmar's coment, which I also thought it is the cause.